Placing an object along an edge over another
I want to place an object along an edge over another, but keep the same angle betwen faces. My English is not good so I hope a couple pictures can show what I want. I put manually a pyramid over a plane. It's placed along one edge keeping two similar angles... I would like to get it with any object/angle. Not sure if it could be done using native tools or it would  involve python scripting.
Perspective


You couldn't do this natively unless you rotate the cube how you want, then apply rotation with Ctrl+A and then activate face snapping with "Align Rotation to Target" enabled. If you wanted it to work dynamically, without having to apply rotation then I think you would need to write your own script for it. As far as I know.

you cannot do it at all with "any" object because no one knows which face of the object should have the same angle...so you should somehow define the faces which should be aligned. So tbh your question is a bit unclear.
